# Python aioconsole stdout.write() to variable

Tags: python, python-asyncio, stdout

I'm trying to get aioconsole input which is used in an asyncio stream into a variable, but when I try the result is None.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import asyncio
import aioconsole

async def main():

    stdin, stdout = await aioconsole.get_standard_streams()
    async for line in stdin:
        result = stdout.write(line) # would not like this line printed
        print(">>>>" + str(result) + "<<<<") # shows None 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**None** is not the result I'm hoping for here. Also, if there's a way to supress the output on the line which I try to set the variable that would be nice as well. Maybe someone can shed some wisdom on what I need to do, tia.

Comment: If you want to print the input, why are your printing the result of an output operation?  Why not just print(line) instead of print(result)?

Comment: @PaulCornelius: The print statement is just an example of the variable that I need the stdout to be. It has nothing to do with `print` it's the variable I need, with the data from `stdout`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You already have a variable containing the data - it's named "line."  You're writing the data to stdout, but the data is still in the variable "line."  All you have to do is print it, or do whatever else you want to do with it.

Comment: @PaulCornelius: That's the problem! I somehow wasn't paying attention to that little detail. Thanks.